# Daylight savings in Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

I've been browsing the docs and took a short look at the code, but could not figure this one out.

Does anyone know wheter Deedle supports DLST (in practice I guess this means multiple values for the same key)?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Deedle does not support having multiple values for the same key. In the latest beta version, this does not actually throw an exception (we need to think about this, thanks for pointing this out!) but it would certainly not work very well.

If you want to store multiple values for the "same key", you can use two-level index where the key is formed by `DateTime * int` (and the `int` is just an index that you use to distinguish the values for the date key). So you can, for example do this (I'm using UK regional setting where the two `DateTime` values are the same):

```
series
  [ (DateTime(2014,3,30).AddHours(1.0).ToUniversalTime(), 0) => 1.0
    (DateTime(2014,3,30).AddHours(2.0).ToUniversalTime(), 1) => 2.0 ]
```

That said, using `DateTime` to represent date with time is [not recommended by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and so it is probably a better idea to use `DateTimeOffset` as the representation of keys (which does not have this problem) and just convert them to local values when you need to e.g. display them to the user...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sems like a good idea to consider this a bit before leaping to implementation...